# Does this result follow immediately by continuous mapping?

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

I'm trying to understand how Theorem 2.3 "immediately implies" Lemma 6.2 (very end of paper) in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.02043.pdf). I'm struggling.

Lemma 6.2 says that the maximum fluctuations of the random function $D_n(t)$ around its limit $D(t)$ are of the order $1/\sqrt{n}$.

> Fix $\epsilon>0$. Then
>   $$\sup_{t \in [\epsilon,1]} |D_n(t) - D(t)| = O_P(1/\sqrt{n})$$

$D_n(t)$ is a function of another random function $\hat{N}_n(1,t)/n$. Theorem 2.3, in turn, basically says that the random function $\hat{N}_n(1,t)/n$ is $O_p(1/\sqrt{n})$.

> Consider the process of re-centered and normalized number of leaves
>   $$G_n(t) := \frac{\hat{N}_n(1,t) - ntp_t^{(\infty)}}{\sqrt{n}}, \quad 0 \leq t \leq 1$$
>   With linear interpolation between time points. Then $G_n$ converges weakly in $D[0,1]$ to a tight Gaussian process.

I think we are done if we can just show that $D_n(t) - D(t)$ is itself $O_P(1/\sqrt{n})$, because that implies the maximum is also stochastically bounded.

Does this follow from the continuous mapping theorem or am I completely overthinking this? I'm having a little bit of a hard time following because we're dealing with random functions. The function $D_n$ is defined for each fixed time point $t$, but at the end of the day we're making assertions about the entire function path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!